# Changing font-size and font-weight dynamically?

Tags: css, less

Is there a way to make `font-size` and `font-weight` change more dynamically using Less?

For instance:

```
@h2font{
   font-size: 32px;
   font-weight: 700;
}
```

or is there another solution to this?

Comment: Are you trying to change it based on an action? Like, click an element and it's weight changes? or gets bigger on hover?

Comment: @WilliamCross no no , neither of those , in page I got like 5-6 h2 titles and I though maybe there is a way to determine h2 font-size and weight as so you can do with colors.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with less.js but typically if you want to change the font size/weight for ALL h2 tags it would look like: `h2{font-size: 32px; font-weight: 700;}`. If you wanted to do it differently you can use id's or classes to setup styling conventions that apply to some but not all. I'm assuming that your @h2font should just be "h2" but I could be wrong due to my lack of knowledge specifically with less.

Comment: @WilliamCross, nah , you are right , I've look for solution with less, but it can't be done as I wrote, so the only possible solution would be as you mentioned. Thanks , mate for you help ;)

Comment: You're welcome! If it's not too much trouble I might write my solution as an "answer", if you can mark it as correct and upvote I'd be grateful :-)

Comment: @WilliamCross, Yea, ofcourse , and one more simple question if you can answer ofcourse. I change my input placeholder style: fonts-size and padding , but I tryed to put some text in my input and when I typ'ed the font seemed to small , is there a way to change that also or it is just default and that's it ?

Comment: the placeholder styling only applies to the placeholder text. If you wanted to style the typed text you could do that using the following CSS: `input[type=text] {  /* Awesome styling */ }`

Comment: @WilliamCross, didn't understood that , could you set an example ?

Comment: there are several types of inputs. If you created a CSS tag for `input { /*styling here*/ }` it would apply to all types. You can invoke the type of input (like text) by using the css tag `input[type=text] { /*styling here*/}` instead. Any css you apply in here will affect all text inputs. You can put properties there like font-size etc to set the size of text that users type into the box, as the placeholder property only styles placeholder text not user inputs.

Comment: `input[type=text]{ font-size: 16pt; }`

Comment: @WilliamCross , thanks again , mate :)

Comment: You're welcome, always happy to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not super familiar with less.js but typically if you want to change the font size/weight for ALL h2 tags it would look like:

```
h2{
    font-size: 32px; 
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

If you wanted to do it differently you can use id's or classes to setup styling conventions that apply to some but not all.

I'm assuming that your @h2font should just be "h2" but I could be wrong due to my lack of knowledge specifically with less. Otherwise you can use JavaScript/jQuery to dynamically change element styling based on user interaction on the page.